# Solr identifying words as spelled correctly when they're not

Tags: solr, spell-checking

I'm following along with the Solr [SpellCheck Component documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpellCheckComponent), but can't seem to get this to work.

The spell checking components seems to be running, but Solr is identifying the word as correctly spelled when it's not.  How can I fix this?

**Example search query results for 'applicatoin' are...**

```
<response>
    <lst name="responseHeader">
        <int name="status">0</int>
        <int name="QTime">0</int>

        <lst name="params">
            <str name="spellcheck">true</str>
            <str name="q">applicatoin</str>
        </lst>
    </lst>

    <result name="response" numFound="0" start="0"/>

    <lst name="spellcheck">

        <lst name="suggestions">
            <bool name="correctlySpelled">true</bool>
        </lst>
    </lst>
</response>
```

**The requestHandler config which is handling this search...**

```
  <requestHandler name="standard" class="solr.SearchHandler" default="true">

     <lst name="defaults">
       <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>

       <str name="spellcheck.extendedResults">true</str>
       <str name="spellcheck.count">1</str>
     </lst>

     <arr name="last-components">
       <str>spellcheck</str>
     </arr>

  </requestHandler>
```

Comment: How SOLR checks, whether word is spelled correct or not:
1) You build SOLR spellchecker`s "dictionary" from your index.
2) SOLR checks the word presence in index, and if it is not there, he thinks, that this word is misspelled. 

Maybe here is your problem? Check spellcheckers index. If your word, which is misspelled is there, then SOLR thinks, that it is not misspelled.

Comment: Regarding "2) SOLR checks the word presence in index, and if it is not there, he thinks, that this word is misspelled.", which index are you referring to? The spellchecker's index or the main index?

Comment: To respond to this question, Yurish is speaking of the solr spellcheker's index.

Comment: Do you perhaps query with a Levenshtein distance defined? E.g `field:applicatoin~0.9`?