# apache solr auto suggestions

Tags: django, solr, django-haystack

I use solr+django-haystack

I set settings.HAYSTACK_INCLUDE_SPELLING = True
and rebuild index

I'm trying to get any suggestion using:
SearchQuerySet().auto_query('tryng ani word
her').spelling_suggestion()

But I always get None

What should I do to get at least one working suggestion ? may be I
need add some configuration into solr config or have some specific
data indexed ?

Comment: I'm having this exact same problem -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329742/solr-identifying-words-as-spelled-correctly-when-theyre-not . I took it down to doing queries manually off of Solr, bypassing haystack to see what the problem is.  I think it's a config in solr somewhere, but idk where.

Comment: Sorry I can't help much, but I recently started using haystack with whoosh for spell suggestions, and it works out of the box. The suggestions are not always perfect, but I almost always get 1 relevant suggestion.

Comment: don't know about haystack, but are you (or haystack) building the dictionary before issuing spelling queries?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what version of solr you're using you could use EdgeNGrams or the [TermsComponent](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/TermsComponent) (if your using 1.4). Check out these links, they should get you started in the right direction. I haven't used haystack, so I don't know if there's an easy way to use leverage these solutions in that framework.

### EdgeNGrams:

www.lucidimagination.com/blog/2009/09/08/auto-suggest-from-popular-queries-using-edgengrams/

### TermsComponent:

wiki.apache.org/solr/TermsComponent

www.lucidimagination.com/search/document/CDRG_ch07_7.13.3

Answer (score 0):

you need to add spelling support to your default request handler in solr conf 
see this please

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpellCheckComponent